# Como hacer un docker con un host independiente?

Tags: docker, redes

Quisiera que un  Docker pueda identificarlo con un host y que sea independiente? podrían por favor decirme como puedo hacer? por ejemplo

```
docker run --name=MYDOCKERSERVICE -p 3001:3001 --network="host" --env-file "/home/ubuntu/server/tiledesk/.env" tiledesk/tiledesk-server
```

Por lo que tengo entendido donde dice network=host Seria el hosting localhost, supongo...  ahora como hago para que tenga su host independiente?? Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker tiene un sistema de networking bastante amplio ([docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/))

Las networks de docker sirven para aislar pequeñas redes de contenedores entre ellas y con el host.

En el caso de `--network="host"` lo que le dices es que use la red del host y por lo tanto lo tanto hará un binding con la ip de la maquina. Por lo que podrás atacarlo via `localhost:3001` o `ip-privada:3001`

También puedes crear una network para ese docker `docker network create foreverAlone` y al arrancar pasa `--network="foreverAlone".

En ese caso todos los dockers que también estén en esa red podrán usar el servicio usando `<dockerName>:3001` pero los dockers que no estén en esa network no podrán verlo

Pero todo eso no tiene que ver con DNS, que es lo que sospecho que quieres.
Es decir, un docker está en la maquina donde está corriendo y por lo tanto el binding se hace con la IP de la máquina.

Si lo que quieres es que una DNS resuelva a ese docker en concreto y con ese puerto concreto entonces tendrás que usar servicios de capas superiores a lo que hace docker network. Por ejemplo [traefik](https://github.com/containous/traefik)